# "No such file" error when using paramiko's sftp

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

I want to file transfer local to server using python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect(hostname, username="username", password="password")

ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls /tmp')

print "output", ssh_stdout.read() 

#Reading output of the executed command

error = ssh_stderr.read()

#Reading the error stream of the executed command

print "err", error, len(error)

#Transfering files to and from the remote machine

sftp = ssh.open_sftp()

#sftp.get("/home/developers/screenshots/ss.txt", "/home/e100075/python/ss.txt")

sftp.put('/home/e100075/python/ss.txt', '/home/developers/screenshots/ss.txt')

sftp.close()

ssh.close()
```

After running i got the errors below

```
File "file_copy.py", line 21, in <module>

    sftp.put('/home/e100075/python/ss.txt', '/home/developers/screenshots/ss.txt')

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 565, in put

    fr = self.file(remotepath, 'wb')

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 245, in open

    t, msg = self._request(CMD_OPEN, filename, imode, attrblock)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 635, in _request

    return self._read_response(num)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 682, in _read_response

    self._convert_status(msg)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 708, in _convert_status

    raise IOError(errno.ENOENT, text)

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file
```

If you know the answer. please let me know

thanks for reading..

Comment: @shx2 thanks, yes i have a file above metioned the path.

Comment: @shx2, i made a mistake on remote directory path. now it's work. Thank  you

Comment: great! I converted my comment to an answer

Answer (score 4):

The problem is most likely that the remote directory does not exist (`/home/developers/screenshots`).  Create the directory and try again.